# Faster than scanf?

Tags: c, input, scanf, numeric-input

I was doing massive parsing of positive integers using `scanf("%d", &someint)`. As I wanted to see if scanf was a bottleneck, I implemented a naive integer parsing function using `fread`, just like:

```
int result;
char c;

while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, stdin), c == ' ' || c == '\n')
    ;

result = c - '0';
while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, stdin), c >= '0' || c <= '9') {
     result *= 10;
     result += c - '0';
}

return result;
```

But to my astonishment, the performance of this function is (even with inlining) about 50% worse. Shouldn't there be a possibility to improve on scanf for specialized cases? Isn't `fread` supposed to be fast (additional hint: Integers are (**edit: mostly**) 1 or 2 digits)?

Comment: Don't you mean `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`

Comment: `scanf`'s probably optimized by the compiler. `fread` is almost definitely *not* optimized to use STDIN as an input.

Comment: At least you should use `fgetc`...

Comment: fread() is certainly not intended to read one character at a time. Presumably even fgetc() performs better.

Comment: If you think the bottleneck might be text conversion, perhaps a better response is to try storing your data as binary rather than text.

Comment: @asveikau No sense in changing his storage format unless he *knows* that it's a bottleneck.

Comment: @jforberg - I agree, but that's a different question.  If he is truly suspicious of it (or simply curious) he can try implementing it and compare results.

Comment: On a nit-picking point of view, I suggest using `isdigit()` instead of `c>='0' && c<='9'`, since digits may not be contiguous in every character set, e.g. EBCDIC.

Comment: @Philip: Digits are consecutive in EBCDIC, even though letters are not.  Special-purpose representations of alphanumeric data may use non-consecutive codings (e.g. Baudot code, used in telecommunications devices for the deaf, maps the digits 1234567890 to the same codes as letters QWERTYUIOP, which are mapped non-consecutively).  I'm unaware of any code which would be used to store data in something one can "fread" from, which would not have digits consecutive.

Comment: `isDigit()` is certainly faster, and not just better because it doesn't assume contiguity: it's faster because it's a single test rather than two, with no internal branch.

Comment: For completeness, `isdigit` is implemented as `(unsigned)c-'0' < 10` in musl libc which is indeed only a single test. In the meantime I changed my test to `c >= '0'` which works for my purposes (only whitespace and digits guaranteed for ASCII input) and is even faster. But the main speedup comes from using `unlocked_stdio(3)`.

Comment: @Philip Inexact; The C Standards have _all_ stated, in 5.2.1 Character sets clause 3, _"In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous"_. It follows that `c>='0' && c<='9'` encompasses all decimal digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The overhead I was encountering was not the parsing itself but the many calls to `fread` (same with `fgetc`, and friends). For each call, the libc has to lock the input stream to make sure two threads aren't stepping on each other's feet. Locking is a very costly operation.

What we're looking for is a function that gives us buffered input (reimplementing buffering is just too much effort) but avoids the huge locking overhead of `fgetc`.

If we can guarantee that there is only a single thread using the input stream, we can use the functions from `unlocked_stdio(3)`, such as `getchar_unlocked(3)`. Here is an example:

```
static int parseint(void)
{
    int c, n;

    n = getchar_unlocked() - '0';
    while (isdigit((c = getchar_unlocked())))
        n = 10*n + c-'0';

    return n;
}
```

The above version doesn't check for errors. But it's guaranteed to terminate. If error handling is needed it might be enough to check `feof(stdin)` and `ferror(stdin)` at the end, or let the caller do it.

My original purpose was submitting solutions to programming problems at SPOJ, where the input is only whitespace and digits. So there is still room for improvement, namely the `isdigit` check.

```
static int parseint(void)
{
    int c, n;

    n = getchar_unlocked() - '0';
    while ((c = getchar_unlocked()) >= '0')
        n = 10*n + c-'0';

    return n;
}
```

It's very, very hard to beat this parsing routine, both performance-wise and in terms of convenience and maintainability.

Answer (score 4):

You'll be able to improve significantly on your example by buffering - read a large number of characters into memory, and then parse them from the in-memory version.

If you're reading from disk you might get a performance increase by your buffer being a multiple of the block size.

Edit: You can let the kernel handle this for you by using [mmap](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/munmap.2.html) to map the file into memory.

Comment: I'd like to doubt that. I'm pretty sure that libc does buffering itself. Unless you're using system calls (read(2)/write(2)), implementing your own buffer is likely to slow things down I think...

Comment: Give it a try - happy to be wrong :) I remember manual buffering dramatically speeding up code that used to be a getc(), BUT that might have been stdin, which isn't block buffered. You could also try giving `setvbuf()` a bigger buffer.

Comment: @JoSo:  Just for kicks, I read a 372MB file with calls to fread with 1 byte at a time and it took nearly 30 seconds.  Reading 4K at a time took 1.3 seconds.  Of course, you have already figured this out.  Nonetheless, accepting this answer would probably be good.

Comment: This wasn't exactly an answer to my question, which was on beating scanf on a more narrow field (`scanf(%d, ...)` is not supposed to do buffering, either!). Anyways accepted because no one else would want to write an answer ;-)

Comment: @JoSo Yes, stdio will buffer, but it is more likely that the bottleneck is simply the 372 million calls to fgetc rather than any side-effects of double buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I use.

```
 #define scan(x) do{while((x=getchar())<'0'); for(x-='0'; '0'<=(_=getchar()); x=(x<<3)+(x<<1)+_-'0');}while(0)
 char _;
```

However, this only works with Integers.

Comment: This works great! Although, I suggest to use getcx() or getchar_unlocked() instead of getchar().

Comment: What does `char _;` do?

Comment: @light2yellow the `char _;` defines a variable whose name is the underscore character, `_`, which is used in the macro itself such as `(_=getchar())`. The intent is to have a global variable which is defined where the macro is defined that the macro then uses. I would probably use `static char _;` instead in order to limit the scope to the file or compilation unit. Probably not a good idea for multi-threaded applications. Really should be a function, not a macro. Reads input for first digit then converts a series of digits into an integer value. stops reading at first non-digit.

Answer (score -2):

From what you say, I derive the following facts:

- numbers are in the range of 0-99, which accounts for 10+100 different strings (including leading zeros)
- you trust that your input stream adheres to some sort of specification and won't contain any unexpected character sequences

In that case, I'd use a lookup table to convert strings to numbers. Given a string s[2], the index to your lookup table can be computed by `s[1]*10 + s[0]`, swapping the digits and making use of the fact that `'\0'` equals `0` in ASCII.

Then, you can read your input in the following way:

```
// given our lookup method, this table may need padding entries
int lookup_table[] = { /*...*/ };

// no need to call superfluous functions
#define str2int(x) (lookup_table[(x)[1]*10 + (x)[0]])

while(read_token_from_stream(stdin, buf))
        next_int = str2int(buf);
```

On today's machines, it will be hard to come up with a faster technique. My guess is that this method will likely run 2 to 10 times faster than any `scanf()`-based approach.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "most" of the numbers are 1 or 2 digits. Anyway, where's the point in using a lookup table? I can't see where you are saving cycles. (You are saving the `c - '0'` part from my solution, but on the other hand you have more redirection)

Comment: Jo So: I'm also saving the `c >= '0' || c <= '9'` and `c == ' ' || c == '\n'` parts with at most three instructions each. But admittedly, a true subset of these operations is needed in what I abbreviated with `read_token_from_stream()`.